# Issue in Flow of Code in st.session_state in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I have written a streamlit script, which basically does the following:

- It asks a user to upload a doc file (pdf, doc etc) in the side bar using file_uploader.
- The code then takes the file, runs it through a bunch of functions/methods imported from a Class script it imports (CustomQnA). The Class basically breaks the text content in the doc into chunks, indexes the content using a vector store and then returns a index retriever object. All that is encapsulated in CustomQnA script.
- When the user uploads the file, ONLY then the text area should be visible in main page of app for user to enter a query. However I see it is appearing even if a file is NOT uploaded but few seconds after the code is run. FIRST ISSUE.
  All of this is defined in a condition ONLY when the file is uploaded as below:

> ```
>  if st.session_state.uploaded_file is not None:
> ```

```
      st.spinner(text = "In Progress")
      custom_qa = call_custom_qna("/Users/abc.pdf") #  
      query = st.text_area("Ask a question here:", height = 100,  key= "query_text")
      button = st.button("Submit", key="button")
      if button:
            st.spinner(text = "Getting Answer...")
            response = custom_qa.qa.run(query)
            st.text_area("Response:", height = 200,  value = response)
```

YET IT shows the text_area even if file is not uploaded. FIRST ISSUE

- Later as you see, if there is no file uploaded then there won't be any other part of code under

> `if st.session_state.uploaded_file is not None:`

should run. yet, even if i remove the file, it still calls all the statements under this condition even when st.session_state.uploaded_file print [].

Here's how the app looks from this script.

[image]

And here is the whole script:

```
    from src.llm_modules_class import CustomQnA
    
    from typing import Any
    import streamlit as st

def get_uploaded_files():
    uploaded_files = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload Files", type=['pdf', 'doc', 'ppt', 'pptx'], accept_multiple_files=True, key ="uploaded_file")
    return uploaded_files
    
    @st.cache_data
    def call_custom_qna(file: Any)-> CustomQnA:
        # Create an instance of CustomQnA class
        custom_qa = CustomQnA()
    
        # Pass the required document
        custom_qa.document_loader(file)
    
        #Run the chunking 
        custom_qa.doc_split()
    
        #Index the chunk-ed docs 
        custom_qa.vector_index()
    
        #Retreive Indexed Vectors 
        custom_qa.index_retriever()
    
        return custom_qa
    
    
    def main():
        container = st.container()
        container.title("Talk to Your Document App")
        uploaded_files = get_uploaded_files()
        print(st.session_state.uploaded_file)
        if st.session_state.uploaded_file is not None:
              st.spinner(text = "In Progress")
              custom_qa = call_custom_qna("/Users/abc.pdf") 
              query = st.text_area("Ask a question here:", height = 100,  key= "query_text")
              button = st.button("Submit", key="button")
              if button:
                    st.spinner(text = "Getting Answer...")
                    response = custom_qa.qa.run(query)
                    st.text_area("Response:", height = 200,  value = response)
                    
                    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

THIRD ISSUE: How do we pass the uploaded file path directly in further code than hardcoding the path. RIGHT NOW I am hardcoding the path of the file uploaded via file_UPLOADER and passing it to call_custom_qna() function. I want it to be read from the uploaded file path directly.